# Map json into cpp objects

Tags: c++, json, rest

I have been searching a technic to map json into cpp objects.

In fact i would like to use a webapi inside my cpp application (as client).

While getting json object is there any existing framework to achieve this ?

So far i have looked **c++ rest sdk**.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Thanks,

K.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but look at this: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923646/is-there-any-way-to-add-parameter-from-json-file-to-vectorobjclass and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884239/how-to-convert-vector-to-json-object-c/55473294#55473294